# Ctrl + B + Arrow Key not working with Tmux

Tags: linux

I've recently started using tmux, but when I try to switch between panes using the "Ctrl+B / 'Arrow Key'" shortcut it only resizes the the active pane.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Do you release Ctrl after pressing B? Is your Ctrl "sticky" in some way? What is the output of `tmux list-keys | grep -E 'prefix *([MCS]-)?(Left|Right|Up|Down)'` when in a shell inside tmux? Please do not respond in comments. [Edit] the question and add information there.

Answer (score 5):

It's <kbd>[prefix]</kbd>, then <kbd>[command key]</kbd> **(not <kbd>[prefix]</kbd> + <kbd>[command key]</kbd>)**

So if you have a default configuration your prefix is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> and your command key is say <kbd>s</kbd> (shows all sessions), so you need to first press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>, release, then press <kbd>s</kbd>.

So with your example it's: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>, then <kbd>Arrow key</kbd> **(not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow key</kbd>)**